# .NET Core (ASP MVC) run after build

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Windows 10, VS2015. I want next

1. Before Build stop previous "dotnet run"
2. After Build run "dotnet run"

Why? I want alway run on http://localhost:5000 web app

What I try

in *project.json* add

```json
"scripts": {
    "postcompile": [ "dotnet run" ]
},
```

**And Build process hang in loop**

Project Web.Core (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because dependencies changed

Compiling Web.Core for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Project Library.Core (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.

Project Web.Core (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.

Compiling Web.Core for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Project Library.Core (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.

Project Web.Core (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.

Compiling MyHome.Web.Core for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Project Library.Core (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.

Project Web.Core (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.

**Questions**

1. how run "dotnet run" after build without loop?
2. how stop previous "dotnet run"?

Answer (score 2):

Current implementation of `dotnet run` calls `dotnet build` inside.
There is an [open request](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3462) to add --no-build parameter, but this can be added in 1.0.0-preview3 or later.